# jQuery Accordion keep menu open from page to page when on child page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following navigation, using the jquery accordion code below. Currently each of the `#top-level` nav items are set to toggle open and close the `<div class="slide">` to reveal the children items. I'd like to modify code so that the `<div class="slide">` stays open when user lands on any of its children.

Screenshot for your reference:
[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li id="top-level" class="has-drop"><a class="opener" href="/index.php/visitor-information/"><em>Visitor Information</em></a>
        <div class="slide">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/index.php/visitor-information/visitor-information/">Visitor Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="/index.php/visitor-information/about-our town/">About our town</a></li>
                <li><a href="/index.php/visitor-information/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="/index.php/visitor-information/im-hungry/">I'm Hungry</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="top-level" class="has-drop"><a class="opener" href="/index.php/membership/"><em>Membership</em></a>
        <div class="slide">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/index.php/membership/membership/">Membership</a></li>
                <li><a href="/index.php/membership/advocacy/">Advocacy</a></li>
                <li><a href="/index.php/membership/ambassadors/">Ambassadors</a></li>
                <li><a href="/index.php/membership/board-of-directors/">Board Of Directors</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="top-level" class=""><a class="opener" href="/index.php/upcoming-events/"><em>Upcoming Events</em></a></li>
    <li id="top-level" class="has-drop"><a class="opener" href="/index.php/online-store/"><em>Online Store</em></a>
        <div class="slide">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/index.php/online-store/online-store/">Online Store</a></li>
                <li><a href="/index.php/online-store/business-compliance-materials/">Business Compliance Materials</a></li>
                <li><a href="/index.php/online-store/events/">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="/index.php/online-store/membership-products/">Membership Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="top-level" class=""><a class="opener" href="/index.php/contact-us/"><em>Contact us</em></a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery Accordian plugin code:

```
/*
 * jQuery Accordion plugin
 */
;(function($){
    $.fn.slideAccordion = function(opt){
        // default options
        var options = $.extend({
            addClassBeforeAnimation: false,
            allowClickWhenExpanded: false,
            activeClass:'active',
            opener:'.opener',
            slider:'.slide',
            animSpeed: 300,
            collapsible:true,
            event:'click'
        },opt);

        return this.each(function(){
            // options
            var accordion = $(this);
            var items = accordion.find(':has('+options.slider+')');

            items.each(function(){
                var item = $(this);
                var opener = item.find(options.opener);
                var slider = item.find(options.slider);
                opener.bind(options.event, function(e){
                    if(!slider.is(':animated')) {
                        if(item.hasClass(options.activeClass)) {
                            if(options.allowClickWhenExpanded) {
                                return;
                            } else if(options.collapsible) {
                                slider.slideUp(options.animSpeed, function(){
                                    hideSlide(slider);
                                    item.removeClass(options.activeClass);
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            // show active
                            var levelItems = item.siblings('.'+options.activeClass);
                            var sliderElements = levelItems.find(options.slider);
                            item.addClass(options.activeClass);
                            showSlide(slider).hide().slideDown(options.animSpeed);

                            // collapse others
                            sliderElements.slideUp(options.animSpeed, function(){
                                levelItems.removeClass(options.activeClass);
                                hideSlide(sliderElements);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                if(item.hasClass(options.activeClass)) showSlide(slider); else hideSlide(slider);
            });
        });
    };

    // accordion slide visibility
    var showSlide = function(slide) {
        return slide.css({position:'', top: '', left: '', width: '' });
    };
    var hideSlide = function(slide) {
        return slide.show().css({position:'absolute', top: -9999, left: -9999, width: slide.width() });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the children being loaded via AJAX or is the menu simply revealing content? If so, it sounds like the anchor tags inside  are hooked up to the click event of your accordion.

I noticed there's an option: "allowClickWhenExpanded" which appears to prevent the slide from hiding on click:

```
if(item.hasClass(options.activeClass)) {
     if(options.allowClickWhenExpanded) {
        return;
     } else if(options.collapsible) {
            slider.slideUp(options.animSpeed, function(){
            hideSlide(slider);
            item.removeClass(options.activeClass);
        });
     }
}
```

So try enabling that to "true" at the top of the function (or when you initialize the accordion).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to auto-expand the navigation menu based on the "current page", you could use jQuery:

```
    if ($('.nav').length > 0)
    {
        var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
        var navLink = $('.nav').find("a[href='/" + currentUrl + "']"); // find current page in navigation

        // find parent
        var parentLink = navLink.parentsUntil('.has-drop').find('.opener');

        // trigger click on accordion, effectively expanding it (assuming menu always starts collapsed)
        parentLink.trigger('click');
    }
```